# Angular 2 getBoundingClientRect from component

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have component like below which is basically a popover:

```
import {Component, Input, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core'

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'popover',
  template: `
  <div id="temp" [ngStyle]="{'position':'absolute', 'z-index':'10000', 'top': y + 'px', left: x + 'px'}"
       [hidden]="hidden" #temp>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  `
})
export class Popover {

  @ViewChild("temp") temp;

  private hidden: boolean = true;
  private y: number = 0;
  private x: number = 0;

  show(target, shiftx = 0, shifty = 0){
    let position = $(target).offset();
    this.x = position.left + shiftx;
    this.y = position.top + shifty;
    this.hidden = false;

    console.log("#temp", this.temp.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()); //all 0s
    console.log("temp id", document.getElementById('temp').getBoundingClientRect()); //all 0s
  }

  hide(){
    this.hidden = true;
  }
}
```

Inside the `show()` method I am trying to get the result of `getBoundingClientRect()` but its returning `0` for all properties but when I type in `document.getElementById("temp").getBoundingClientRect()` from Chrome's console I get proper result with actual values in the properties. Why the difference and what can I do to get the actual value from my component?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a difference. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I suspect that Dom is not update yet to give you correct size. Can you wrap the console statement in setTimeout to see if that works.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal Yeah `setTimeout()` did the trick :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, the DOM was not updated right after it was shown so, a `setTimeout` e.g. 10 did the trick.

Comment: a setTimout of **0** is usually enough

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using setTimeout or lifecycle hooks that can be triggered more than once, I solved it with setting the Renderer to watch the window load event.

```
import { OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

...

export class MyComponent implements  OnInit {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private render: Renderer2) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.render.listen('window', 'load', () => {
            const rect = this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        })
    }

}
```

Maybe this helps someone's usecase.

Answer (score 5):

I would use ngAfterContentChecked(). It works perfectly fine for me.

```
import { AfterContentChecked  } from '@angular/core';

export class ModelComponent implements AfterContentChecked  {
   ngAfterContentChecked() {
        //your code
    }
}
```

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: Works well on directive to get the `ElementRef` `getBoundingClientRect` as well. Thanks.

Comment: Note: `AfterContentChecked` is called after the `ngAfterContentInit()` and EVERY subsequent `ngDoCheck()`.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, `ngAfterContentChecked` works. As answered above.

`ngAfterContentChecked` hook method runs last in the lifecycle before the `ngOnDestroy`. You can read more about Lifecycle Hooks [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Also be careful what you do in here, as it may result into performance issue.

> ***Timing***
>
> *Called after the ngAfterViewInit() and every subsequent
>   ngAfterContentChecked().*